# What is the best way to get location of users and show on the spring boot web application

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, google-maps, geolocation

I i have spring boot web application and a react native mobile application, and all of the oprations in the mobile application doing by call APIs that exists in the web application.

Now, in the specific form in the web application, system administrator wants to see the realtime location of users.

What is the best to do this and make communication with mobile application.

I doesn't have enough information about react native and mobile developments.

Comment: If you are working with Android devices, you can check [Location data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location) documentation that can be used with Google Maps. There are several ways to get the location data but the most recommended one is [The Google Play services Location API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location#the_google_play_services_location_api)